# multi-statement table-valued function problem

Tags: sql-server-2008, dynamic-programming, dynamic-sql, sql-function

I have problem with multi-statement table-valued function  . Whats wrong whit this code

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON;
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON;
GO

CREATE FUNCTION FN_BFS_CFS_BALANCE_VIW
(
    @param1 VARCHAR
)
RETURNS @table TABLE
(
    DAT VARCHAR
  , COD_ACN_KOL VARCHAR
  , DES_ACN_KOL VARCHAR
  , COD_ACN_MOIN VARCHAR
  , DES_ACN_MOIN VARCHAR
  , COD_ACN_TAFSIL VARCHAR
  , DES_ACN_TAFSIL VARCHAR
  , COD_FAREI1 VARCHAR
  , DES_FAREI1 VARCHAR
  , COD_FAREI2 VARCHAR
  , DES_FAREI2 VARCHAR
  , TYP_FRGN INT
  , DES_FRGN VARCHAR
  , TYP_DPN INT
  , DES_DPN VARCHAR
  , FLG_129 INT
  , DES_129 VARCHAR
  , AMN_DBT INT
  , AMN_CRD INT
  , COD_MONEY VARCHAR
  , DES_MONEY VARCHAR
  , AMN_DBT_FRGN INT
  , AMN_CRD_FRGN INT
)
AS
BEGIN

    EXEC (' call tpout.set_context(''PARAM1'',' + '' + @param1 + '' + ' AT [LS_New2CFS]');

    SELECT DAT
         , COD_ACN_KOL
         , DES_ACN_KOL
         , COD_ACN_MOIN
         , DES_ACN_MOIN
         , COD_ACN_TAFSIL
         , DES_ACN_TAFSIL
         , COD_FAREI1
         , DES_FAREI1
         , COD_FAREI2
         , DES_FAREI2
         , TYP_FRGN
         , DES_FRGN
         , TYP_DPN
         , DES_DPN
         , FLG_129
         , DES_129
         , AMN_DBT
         , AMN_CRD
         , COD_MONEY
         , DES_MONEY
         , AMN_DBT_FRGN
         , AMN_CRD_FRGN
    FROM LS_New2CFS..TPOUT.BFS_CFS_BALANCE_VIW;


    RETURN;

END;
```

when I execute this code this error showing up.

PS: `[LS_New2CFS]` is Oracle link server. `[BFS_CFS_BALANCE_VIW]` is a view in the Oracle database.

> Msg 444, Level 16, State 2, Procedure FN_BFS_CFS_BALANCE_VIW, Line 37 [Batch Start Line 5]
> Invalid use of a side-effecting operator 'EXECUTE STRING' within a function.
>
> Msg 443, Level 16, State 14, Procedure FN_BFS_CFS_BALANCE_VIW, Line 33 [Batch Start Line 5]
> Select statements included within a function cannot return data to a client.

Thanks to you

Comment: Functions can't call stored procedures. Also, to use a Multi-statement TVF, you need to insert the data to the table you have declared in the function, then return that table. i.e. `INSERT @table (<columns>) SELECT <columns> FROM dbo.View; RETURN @Table;`.       As an aside, this is probably worth a read: [Bad Habits to Kick : Declaring VARCHAR without (length)](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/09/bad-habits-to-kick-declaring-varchar-without-length)

Comment: Just as a side note: SQL Server 2008 and 2008 R2 are **out of extended support** by now - https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/sql/database-administration/the-end-of-sql-server-2008-and-2008-r2-extended-support/ - time to upgrade!

Comment: Hey Gareth thanks its work. And I tried to fix my habits.